# passing values from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have two comboboxes and one file_field in the view file. I want to save the values of the selected values in the comboboxes and the path of the file selected and send these values back to controller. How can I do it?

```
<% form_for :path, :url => {controller => "users", :action => "receive_file"} do |f| %>

  <div align='center' >

    <font color='black'><b>Select Skillset:</b>
      <%= collection_select(:video, :category_id, @technologies, :id, :SkillSetName) %>
    </font>
    <br><br><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font color='black'><b>Select Topic:</b>
      <%= collection_select(:video, :category_id, @technologies, :id, :Topic) %> 
    </font>
    <br><br><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= file_field "person", "photo" %>
    <br><br>
    <%= submit_tag "Append", :style=>"height: 25px; width: 100px"%>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code in...

Comment: code is in html and as i paste the code the tags disappear

Comment: select all the code and click the {} button above the text area.

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation a tad to make it more readable. I don't have any clue what the </td> matches on the 3rd to last line of the code...the edit is waiting for peer review

Comment: for one thing, dude, stop using tables for your layout, and font tag is deprecated, and use css instead of 4 < br >s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what forms are for. Please note that it is a separate request and you can embed all you data as form fields in the view. Once the user clicks on submit, all the fields of the form will be available in the params hash in the controller action (to which the form is submitted)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html